# x86 Assembly Memory - What does the "add" instruction do?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Memory Segment Below.

On the first add instruction (add eax, 3), it moves the pointer for eax 3 spots to the right.

Thus, EAX = 12, 17, A3, 00. (This I understand)

But, on the second add instruction (add ebx, 5), it actually adds the value 5 to ebx,

making EBX = 12, 17, A3, **05**.

Why is that?

(Little Endian)

[image]
[image]

Comment: _Thus, EAX = 12, 17, A3, 00."_  In nasm syntax `mov eax, var1` means `eax = address of var1`, not `eax = value at var1`. As for why the least significant byte of `ebx` ends up with the value 5; the byte at `var1+3` is initially 0. 0 + 5 = 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'add reg, (something)'     adds that value to the register, period. The difference you are seeing is how you are using the registers.

As you are doing 'mov ebx,[eax]' you are using the value in eax as a pointer, because you are de-referencing it with the square brackets.